# Setting Default Values in ViewModel without listing properties in View - possible? MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int setId)
{
    // create new viewModel
    var model = new CreateCardViewModel() {SetId = setId};

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCardViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var set = _db.Sets.Single(s => s.SetId == viewModel.SetId);
        var card = new Card
            {
                Set=set, 
                SetId = set.SetId, 
                Sides = viewModel.Sides, 
                DateCreated = viewModel.DateCreated, 
                IsReady = viewModel.IsReady, 
                Stage = viewModel.Stage
            };
        set.Cards.Add(card);

        _db.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("detail", "set", new {setId = viewModel.SetId});
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

With the following ViewModel:

```
public class CreateCardViewModel
    {
        public CreateCardViewModel()
        {
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            Sides = new List<Side> {new Side() {Stage = 0, IsFront = true, IsReady = false, Content = "Blank Side"}};
            Stage = 0;
            IsReady = true;
        }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int SetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<Side> Sides { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Stage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsReady { get; set; }

}
```

However when I post back from my view, none of the data from my `ViewModel` makes it back to the controller, because the view doesn't ever see it.  What's the best way to create these default values without having to list them in the `View`?  It just seems inelegant to list parameters in the view.  Perhaps I should be setting these default values in the `Controller`?

My View is here:

```
@model Project.Models.CreateCardViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreateCardViewModel</legend>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Sides.Count; i++)
        {
            <h3>Side @(i+1)</h3>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sides[i].Content)
        }

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Can you post your view? Is your view strongly-typed?

Comment: Do the users input any sides? Otherwise since that data is only stored in the view model, you can probably just factor out a method which you can call once you get the user filled model back which will include the static side.

Comment: They will be posting their own Sides, but every Card's first Side will have some default values.  I'll post the view now - thanks for the help.

Comment: Although you can pass the data from the view to the controller by adding properties to the form, or through the use of hidden fields, I agree that you should populate the default values you need in your controller or in a repository/data access layer (when using repository patern).